# Bouncing multiple lines with fixed coordinates off walls in java graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I want to store the fixed coordinates and then increment the coordinates until they reache the edge of the screen.
Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Name extends JPanel
{
int x, y, w, h, xdir, ydir;


public Name ()
{
}
public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent (g);

    g.drawLine(110+x, 300+y, 95+x, 400+y);
    g.drawLine(110, 300, 123, 350);
    g.drawLine(135, 300, 123, 350); //M
    g.drawLine(135, 300, 150, 400);


    g.drawOval (150, 300, 15, 15);            // i
    g.fillOval (150, 300, 15, 15);
    g.drawLine (155, 320, 155, 400);
    g.drawLine (172, 300, 172, 400);     // k
    g.drawLine (172, 350, 185, 300);
    g.drawLine (172, 350, 185, 400);

    g.drawLine (190, 360, 265, 360);     // e
    g.drawArc (190, 325, 75, 75, 360, 180);
    g.drawArc (190, 330, 75, 75, 168, 180);
    w = getSize ().width;
    h = getSize ().height;
    xdir = 1;
    ydir = 1;
    x = x + xdir;
    y = y+ ydir;
    if (x > w || x < 0)
    {
        xdir = -1 * xdir;
    }
    if (y > h || y < 0)
    {
        ydir = -1 * ydir;
    }
    repaint ();
    MyLib.delay (25);
} // paint method


public static void main (String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("NameBounce");
    frame.getContentPane ().add (new Name ());
    frame.setSize (500, 500);
    frame.setVisible (true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
} // main method
} // Name class
```

I've tried storing the coordinates into array lists but had no luck.

I've been trying to avoid hard coding the entire program.

Comment: *"I've been trying to avoid hard coding the entire program."*  Try asking a question..

Answer (score 2):

Use something like [`Path2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html) to define the shapes you want to draw (you can draw all the letters within a single `Path2D`)

Use a [`AffineTransform`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) to translate the location of the `Graphics` and `Graphics2D#draw` to physically paint the `Path2D`

Use a Swing `Timer` to schedule a regular call back within which you can update the position of the `Path2D` and call `repaint` on the component to trigger an update

See

- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

for more details

Don't call `Thread.sleep` or any other blocking process within the `paintComponent` method (or from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread) as this will prevent the EDT from updating the screen.

Make sure you are creating/updating your UI only from within the context of the EDT, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details